# JQuery UI draggable and droppable need to click twice to get drag div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying writing a puzzle game using JS and JQuery so in this scenario I'm using JQuery Draggable and Droppable feature for swap 2 puzzle elements. code is working nicely but the problem is after initial the draggable need to double click on the div to get drag.

Here is my HTML Genarate part:

```
function partitionToDiv() {
  document.getElementById('submitbtn').disabled=true;
  gridSize = document.getElementById('level').value;
  var wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper');
  wrapper.classList.add("background");
  var parent =  document.getElementById('wrapper');
  var widthOfWrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper').offsetWidth;
  var heightOfWrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper').offsetHeight;
  var cellSize = (600/gridSize);
  var cellSizeParsIntVal = parseInt(600/gridSize);
  document.getElementById('wrapper').setAttribute("style","width:"+(widthOfWrapper+cellSizeParsIntVal)+"px");
  document.getElementById('wrapper').setAttribute("style","height:"+(heightOfWrapper+cellSizeParsIntVal)+"px");
  for (var j=0; j < gridSize; j++) {
    for (var i=0; i < gridSize; i++) {
      var rows = document.createElement('div')
      rows.classList.add('panel');
      rows.classList.add('ui-draggable');
      rows.classList.add('ui-draggable-handle');
      rows.setAttribute("id", "ids")
      rows.style.width = parseInt(cellSize)+ "px"
      rows.style.height = parseInt(cellSize)+ "px"
      var i_int = parseInt(i*cellSize*-1);
      var j_int = parseInt(j*cellSize*-1);
      rows.style.backgroundPosition = i_int + ' ' + j_int ;
      parent.appendChild(rows);
      arrayForTakeValue.push(rows);
      arrayForTakeValOfBegin.push(rows);
      if(i_int !== parseInt(-600+(cellSize)) || j_int !== parseInt(-600+(cellSize))){
        rows.style.backgroundRepeat = "no-repeat";
        rows.style.backgroundImage = "url('./img/dog.jpg')";
      }else {
        rows.setAttribute("id", "empty");
        rows.classList.add('ui-droppable');
        CountStart();
      }
    }    
  }
}
```

This part is for Draggable and Droppable:

```
$(document).on("click",".panel", function(){
      var emptyDiv = document.getElementById('empty');
      var emtDiv = $("div").index(emptyDiv);
      var selDiv = ($("div").index(this));
      if((selDiv -1 === emtDiv && ((emtDiv)%parseInt(gridSize))!== 0) || (selDiv+1 === emtDiv && (selDiv%parseInt(gridSize))!== 0) ||
         (selDiv - parseInt(gridSize)) === emtDiv || (selDiv + parseInt(gridSize)) === emtDiv ){

        $(".panel").draggable({
         snap: '#empty',
         revert: "invalid", 
         snapMode: 'outer', 
         helper: "clone",
         cursor: "crosshair"
         });

        $("#empty").droppable({
          drop: function (event, ui) {
           var dragElem = ui.draggable;
           var empty = $('#empty')
           var emptyPanel = empty.clone();
           var selectedPanel = dragElem.clone();
           empty.replaceWith(selectedPanel);
           dragElem.replaceWith(emptyPanel);
           window.moves++;
           $("#counter span").html(window.moves);
           var wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper')
           var childNodes = wrapper.childNodes;
           var val = 0;
           for(var i = 0; i<arrayForTakeValOfBegin.length; i++){
            if(arrayForTakeValOfBegin[i].style.backgroundPosition == childNodes[i].style.backgroundPosition) {
            val++;
          if(val === arrayForTakeValOfBegin.length) {
            window.obj.Stop(); 
            $('.btnclass').empty().html($('#gameOver').html());
            $(".stepCount span").html(moves);             
         $("#timeCountspan").html(secondsTimeSpanToHMS(window.index));
          }
         }
        }
       }
      });
     }
    });
```

So I need to get drag using a single click. what is wrong with me? any suggestion, please.

Comment: im not complete  the post at that movement and working with edit.

Comment: Great, thanks. This looks good, but adding HTML and CSS would be very helpful. You can use a [stack snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) to embed the whole app into the post.

Comment: OK sure.. Thanks for advice. i will edit code with HTML and CSS code.

Comment: I think something cut off part of your code:

    console.log(moves)
    span").html(secondsTimeSpanToHMS(window.index));

Comment: OH.. thanks.. corrected.